# Does each client in a wifi network receive each data packet of HTTP replies?

Tags: security, session, https, wifi, session-cookies

**As we all know, HTTPS is a way to protect against session hijacking.**

Suppose this isn't an option for some application. Further suppose, users connect to the web-application using a **strongly encrypted (WPA2) wifi network**.

Fact: WPA2 protects against third parties, which didn't connect correctly to the wifi network.

**But does WPA2 additionally protected each legitimate user against each other legitimate user? Does each legitimate user has a securely isolated channel to the wifi router?**

Or does the wifi router works more like a hub: If the wifi router needs to send data to a wifi client, it broadcasts it to all clients - so that each client can read the data?

> Speaking of web application programming: Do we need to use HTTPS in a
>   WPA2 protected wifi network to protect each wifi client against each
>   other wifi client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Wi-Fi, as the transmission medium is the air, every STA could intercept data from others STA. So, for this point, you can compare a Wi-Fi network to a hub.

In fact, the 802.11 stack take care of the PHY and the MAC/LLC layers.

[image: 802.11 stack]

Moreover, the WPA/WPA2 encryption is just here to protect foreign STA to read your Wi-Fi network frames.

It's very easy to test, use [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) with two STAs on the same AP. You should be able to see frames form the other STA.

So if you want to protect a web application on a network which use Wi-Fi (and/or hub *but not only*), **the use of HTTPS is strongly recommended**.